# Several Zabbix proxies in Zabbix sender

Tags: zabbix

I use trapper items type for sending data by using Zabbix sender.

However, from time to time due to failover/other cases those hosts which are being monitored by Zabbix Proxy change Zabbix proxy from one to another. As a result Zabbix new proxy rejects data which is being sent by sender as long as sender uses an old Zabbix proxy.

Therefore is there a way to overcome this obstacle and make sender use several Zabbix proxies to avoid data rejection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `zabbix_sender` always send data to multiple proxies, ignoring the fact that one/some proxies will reject the data. This would have to be done in your scripts.

But when you say "failover", it might be worth using this same failover process to redirect `zabbix_sender`, too.